# Use OpenSSH agent instead of the OSX agent

Tags: homebrew, ssh, launchd

I've installed OpenSSH using homebrew (`brew install openssh`) and this installation provides it's own `ssh-agent`.

Still, when I login, and see the autostarted ssh-agent, I see that the agent that is started is the OS X agent, and not the one installed via Homebrew OpenSSH.

Also, how do I start the `ssh-agent` from openssh by default every time that I login? Finally, is there any way in which I can automatically load key files to the openssh agent, and have these key files loaded the next time that I login as well?

Answer (score 5):

`ssh-agent`, the system builtin one, is run as a system daemon started by `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist`. Cause the service `plist` is located in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`, it mean it's impossible to disable it unless you break SIP, which is not recommended.

The macOS version `ssh-agent` is built with additional KeyChain support compared with the standard one. The best solution is to use the keychain.

First, uninstall the homebrew-installed SSH, `brew uninstall openssh`.

Secondly, configure the SSH to use password from Keychain.

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
# use the password stored in keychain
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Thirdly, add the key and password into Keychain.

```sh
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

In this solution, we keep the password into Keychain and configure OpenSSH to load password for the key from Keychain.

References

- [OpenSSH updates in macOS 10.12.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2449/_index.html)

Comment: Since you've recommended uninstalling `openssh`, note that you aren't using openssh, but rather the macos version of ssh. Which is like openssh but is either missing some connection options of openssh or has different names for these options. What I did realize though, was that openssh works well with the macos ssh-agent. So that's what I am using now.

Comment: FYI, you cannot have a comment at the end of a line in `~/.ssh/config`: `UseKeychain yes # use the password stored in keychain`. You will get the error message `garbage at end of line; "#"`

Comment: @wisbucky Thx. I forgot that ssh config doesn't support inline comment.

Comment: Additional differences between the agents: the macos version doesn't seem to support id_ecdsa_sk keys.  When adding one it always returns `agent refused operation`.  The agent in openssh accepts that key just fine.

Comment: Another diff: Mac ssh doesn't seem to tab complete file paths, etc, which significantly slows down ad hoc sftp sessions.

Comment: the mac version of ssh-agent does not support FIDO keys; "No FIDO SecurityKeyProvider specified"